# Filtro jpa jpql sem a utilização do filtro do primefaces (com método próprio)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa

Alterada para provável solução porem ainda não está funcionando, me parece que não se atualiza a linha com o ajax.

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="formTableProd">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/master.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="conteudo">

            <h2>
                <p:outputLabel value=" Filtro e ações para produtos" />
            </h2>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <p:outputLabel value="Filtro:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{mbProduto.produto.nomeProduto}" size="50"
                    maxlength="150" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
                </p:inputText>
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="Filtrar"
                    action="#{mbProduto.filtroPersonalizado}" update="@form">
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:dataTable id="tableProduto" value="#{mbProduto.resultado}"
                var="produtos" paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
                {FirstPageLink}
                {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
                {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}
                {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" style="width: 98%" lazy="true"
                rowKey="#{produtos.idProduto}" selectionMode="single">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Cod.:" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.idProduto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nome:" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.nomeProduto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Esf.:" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.especificacaoProduto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="X.:" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.medidaX}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Y.:" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.medidaY}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="R$ Venda" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtos.precoDeMetroVenda}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Ações" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="Excluir um produto"
                        action="#{mbProduto.excluir}" id="produtos" ajax="false"
                        onclick="if(!confirm('Deseja excluir #{produtos.nomeProduto}  ?')) return false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{produtos}"
                            target="#{mbProduto.produto}" />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s"
                        title="Alterar um produto"
                        action="#{mbProduto.direcionarAlteracao}" update="tableProduto"
                        process="@this" ajax="true">
                        <f:ajax execute="@form" update="produtos.idProduto"
                            render=":tableProduto"></f:ajax>
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{produtos}"
                            target="#{mbProduto.produto}" />
                    </p:commandButton>



                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-plus"
                        title="Adicionar um produto" action="#{mbProduto.novo}" />

                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:form>
```

meu get da lista e meu método para trazer o filtro, agora os dois referenciam a mesma lista.

```
public List<Produto> getResultado(){
     if(resultado == null){
            resultado = new ArrayList<Produto>();
            EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
            Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Produto a", Produto.class);
            this.resultado = q.getResultList();
            em.close();    
        }
        return resultado;

}

public String filtroPersonalizado() {
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    String consulta = "select p from Produto p where p.nomeProduto = :nome";
    TypedQuery<Produto> query = em.createQuery(consulta, Produto.class);
    query.setParameter("nome", produto.getNomeProduto());
    this.resultado = query.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return "";
}
```

A situação agora é a seguinte, ele atualiza o filtro carrega na minha EL porem ele não consegue encontrar quando pressiono o botão para editar o mesmo, no caso ele enxerga como se fosse o antigo, ou seja sempre traz o primeiro da lista.

Comment: Por que você não usa o ***filter*** do próprio PrimeFaces? Ele já faz o trabalho pra você. Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).

Comment: Siga o exemplo de DataTable Lazy do Primefaces que não tem erro: [DataTable - Lazy](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml)

Comment: eu não gostaria de utilizar o filtro do primefaces.

Comment: Eu não gostaria de utilizar o filtro do primefaces pois não quero que minha aplicação fique presa a esse frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido, a solução requer um pouco de estudo rs mas isso é bem legal e acho que vale a pena colocar aqui, então vamos lá.

O que acontece é o seguinte sempre que eu filtrava o conteúdo ele sempre ia para a mesma página assim o request(Requisição) sempre respondia para a mesma página e o jsf não consegue compreender isso, bom isso pelo que li sobre o assunto é questão de escopo tenho que colocar todos os créditos possíveis ao detentor desse blog, http://blog.gilliard.eti.br, então vamos lá ver o que mudou.

1: definir um converter para tratar o retorno e converter para o que eu quiser.

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import br.com.drem.entity.Produto;
import br.com.drem.util.JPAUtil;

@FacesConverter(forClass=Produto.class)
public class ProdutoConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String string) {
    System.out.println("ProdutoConverter.getAsObject(): " + string);
    if(string == null || string.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    return JPAUtil.getEntityManager().find(Produto.class, Long.valueOf(string));
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    Produto produto = (Produto) object;
    System.out.println("ProdutoConverter.getAsString(): " + produto);
    if(produto == null || produto.getIdProduto() == null){
        return null;
    }
    return String.valueOf(produto.getIdProduto());
}
```

}

2: mudar meu controller para ViewScoped

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.drem.dao.ProdutoDao;
import br.com.drem.entity.Produto;
import br.com.drem.managebean.produtoMb.rn.RegraNegocioProduto;
import br.com.drem.util.JPAUtil;

/**
 * @author AndreMart
 * @contacts: andremartins@outlook.com.br;andre.drem@gmail.com
 * @tel: 63 8412 1921
 * @site: drem.com.br
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "mbProduto") @ViewScoped
public class MbProduto implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Produto produto;
private ProdutoDao produtoDao;
private List<Produto> resultado;

public MbProduto() {
    this.produtoDao = new ProdutoDao();
    this.produto = new Produto();
}

public void setResultado(List<Produto> resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}

public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public ProdutoDao getProdutoDao() {
    return produtoDao;
}

public void setProdutoDao(ProdutoDao produtoDao) {
    this.produtoDao = produtoDao;
}

public String novo() {
    RegraNegocioProduto.limpProduto();
    return "pgproduto";
}

public String salvar() {
    RegraNegocioProduto.salvar(produto);
    //atribuirEstadoInicial();
    return "pgtbproduto" + "?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String excluir() {
    RegraNegocioProduto.excluir(produto);
    return "pgtbproduto" + "?faces-redirect=true";
}


public List<Produto> getResultado(){
     if(resultado == null){
            resultado = new ArrayList<Produto>();
            EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
            Query q = em.createQuery("select a from Produto a", Produto.class);
            this.resultado = q.getResultList();
            em.close();    
        }
        return resultado;

}

public String filtroPersonalizado() {
    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    String consulta = "select p from Produto p where p.nomeProduto = :nome";
    TypedQuery<Produto> query = em.createQuery(consulta, Produto.class);
    query.setParameter("nome", produto.getNomeProduto());
    this.resultado = query.getResultList();
    em.close();
    return "";
}
}
```

3: Alterar o componete que faz o response para a EL que editará (só foi mudado esse botão nada mais), note que foi adicionado um redirecionamento de página e para o jsf aceitar esses dados ficarem vivos com o @ViewSoped precisamos passar os mesmos pela url para isso se faz includeViewParams=true"

```
<h:commandButton value="edit"
                        title="Alterar um produto"
                        action="pgproduto?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{produtos}" target="#{mbProduto.produto}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
```

4: Na página que receberá os dados colocar um viewParam, basicamente esse componente seria como um input a diferença seria que o usuário não digita nada, apenas recebe os parâmetros que no caso é o próprio obj, passado na url e o jsf encarrega do resto(mas você sempre deve definir as entradas)

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{mbProduto.produto}" />
    </f:metadata>
```

Demorei muito até entender o que estava acontecendo, isso prova que para programar precisa estudar muito, e não saindo metendo a cara no código.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ser feito alterando o método de pesquisa pra que ele preencha a lista `#{mBProduto.produto}` com os valores filtrados no seu método e, posteriormente, atualizando os dados (a mesma lista da `<p:dataTable>`) do formulário com o Ajax do `<p:commandButton>`.

O `<p:commandButton>` ficaria assim com o `update`:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="Filtrar"
                action="#{mbProduto.filtroPersonalizado}"
                update="@form">
</p:commandButton>
```

Desse modo, os dados na página serão os mesmos do método `filtroPersonalizado()` sempre que a pesquisa for acionada pelo botão.

Comment: Opa cara blz, seguinte fiz como você falou mas ainda sim ele não está trazendo o desejado, ele sempre enxerga as linhas da tabela como se tivessem sem o filtro. ela está em https://github.com/AndreMart/comunicaVisual/blob/master/WebContent/admin/pgtbproduto.xhtml essa é a EL de produto também tem a controller https://github.com/AndreMart/comunicaVisual/blob/master/src/br/com/drem/managebean/produtoMb/MbProduto.java dá uma força... o0

Comment: editei o post acima para você ver como ficou.

Comment: Estranho não funcionar como está. Tenho uma página que faz o mesmo esquema que o seu, porém faço o `update` para o ID da `<p:dataTable>`. Tente colocar o `update="tableProduto`.

Comment: fiz também esse teste, me pergunto qual escopo você está utilizando, se eu colocar @SessionScope até dá certo porem o objeto fica na sessão ai vira uma bagunça ai fica no requestScop que é o default mesmo. você teria um exemplo de um filtro que vc fez só para eu comparar, por que também não vejo o erro, talvez no gitHub.com

Comment: Tenta colocando @ViewScope, no meu caso usei ele.

Comment: olha a solução que consegui, o que acha?